# Exporting backup from Heroku Postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to export heroku backup from heroku to my local machine. I'm using next command: `heroku pg:backups capture`and `curl -o latest.dump heroku pg:backups public-url`. The last one gives me the next ouput:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: heroku
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: pg
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: public-url
```

When I'm trying to replace `heroku pg:backups public-url` with url, that leads to the database (that I got using `heroku pg:backups public-url` command), I'm getting the next:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
'X-Amz-Credential' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'X-Amz-Date' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'X-Amz-Expires' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'X-Amz-SignedHeaders' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'X-Amz-Signature' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So how I resolve it and export heroku postgres to local machine? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

The single liner you are looking for is:

```
curl -o latest.dump $(heroku pg:backups public-url | cat)
```

Now about the error: Can you download that url (`heroku pg:backups public-url | cat`) in the browser? Are you on a Mac? Could you run and report back the results of `openssl version`